# Is there a plugin to highlight a marked text?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

So basically what I am trying to find out if there is a plugin for eclipse which can highlight a word or a part of text which I select.

If not is there any fast way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I use this plugin : eclipse-glance
https://code.google.com/archive/p/eclipse-glance/

It's a old plugin I use on Eclipse Mars.

Comment: This is a searchfunction which is not what I was looking for but thank you anyways for your effort. I was looking for a coloring plugin which colors a selected(marked per mouse) piece of code in a different color.